# Understanding FAST search versions

Tags: fast-esp, fast-for-sharepoint

FAST search seems to come in several flavors including:
"FAST Search Server for Internal Applications" (FSIA) and 
"FAST Search Server for Internet Sites"

Are these separate SKUs? Are they available on MSDN download for universal subscribers?

Also what about "FAST Search Designer for Microsoft Visual Studio"?

I am trying to evaluate if I can use FAST to do web crawling with data mining and text analytics; so far I have been unable to find any simple and clear explanations on the web on how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several questions at once and I'll try to answer them one at a time (next time one question per post please)

*Several flavors*: There are basically two FAST versions - one for SharePoint and one that is the old FAST ESP.

- "FAST Search Server for SharePoint 2010", FS4SP, that's FAST integrated with SharePoint for enterprise scenarios
- "FAST Search Server for Internal Applications", FSIA, that's FAST ESP for internal sites
- "FAST Search Server for Internet Servers", FSIS, that's FAST ESP for internet sites

*SKU's*. Yes, they are separate SKUS's. AFAIK only FS4SP is available for download on MSDN/TechNet for subscribers.

*FAST Search Designer for Microsoft Visual Studio* - I've never heard of anything like that.

*FAST capabilities*. The reasons you specify here is the main reasons to go to FAST compared to SharePoint standard search. Yes you can do a whole lotta fun and customize the FAST pipeline until you bleed. Big difference between FS4SP and ESP is that you are limited in what parts of the FAST pipeline you can modify in FS4SP. Here is one example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795797.aspx